# get_the_terms() not returning expected result

Tags: terms

I have created 3 custom taxonomies to tag my posts with. On my single.php template I am attempting to count the number of terms, using [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) for each custom taxonomy that is assigned to the post, but it is not producing the result I am expecting.

I have two custom taxonomies called "sizes" and "colors" and I am getting the number of terms from these taxonomies like this:

```
<?php
    $sizeCount = count(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'sizes'));
    $colorCount = count(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'colors'));

    echo $sizeCount . ' ' . $colorCount;
?>
```

The issue is that this always seems to return at least 1(never 0), even if the post isn't tagged with any of the terms from that taxonomy. For instance, I have a post tagged with `1` size term and `0` color terms. However, this returns `1 1` when it should be returning `1 0`. If I tag it with another size, the sizeCount correctly outputs and I get `2 1`.

Does anyone know why I am getting a `1` even when the post is not tagged with any terms from that taxonomy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to get the number of terms your post have, then you should use `wp_get_post_terms()`.

```
$sizeCount = count(wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'sizes'));
$colorCount = count(wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'colors'));

echo $sizeCount . ' ' . $colorCount;
```